# Take greater value as 0 from array and preview and ignore another value which contains 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add values to a select html element using Jquery/Ajax.
The values are returned by a PHP script which I call with ajax.

Code Ajax:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fds_categories').change(function () {
            var template_id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'username' : '<?php echo $user->username; ?>',
                    'categorie_id' : template_id
                },
                url: "ajax/fds_template_ajax.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#fds_price').empty();
                    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, element) {
                        $('#fds_price').append(

                            $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + element.p + ' Zbucks')
                        );
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Part Code PHP:

```
$response['template'][$key] = array(
    "name" => (string)$template['name'],
    "id" => (string)$template['id'],
    "active" => (string)$template['active'],
    "assetUrl" => (string)$template['assetUrl'],
    "consumable" => (string)$template['consumable'],
    "new" => (string)$template['new'],
    "pb" => (string)$template['pb'],
    "p" => (string)$template['p'],
    "zch" => (string)$template['zch']
);
```

**My problem is the following:**

The returned array does contain two different values for prices: pb = Premium currency, p = Basic currency. But only 1 value is actually filled with a value.

**For example:**

Item A:

pb = 0

p = 1000

**Screenshot:** https://gyazo.com/63757fcadbeb1172e8b045d545ff8805

---

Question:

How would I be able to add the value > 0 to the preview and to ignore the value = 0 ?

For example:

Item B costs p = 100 and pb = 0, now I want the p to show up. Item C costs p = 0 and pb = 10, now I want the pb to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume both properties always have value, 0 or a number greater than 0. You can use:

```
$('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + Math.max(element.p, element.pb)  + ' Zbucks')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple condition :

```
if(parseInt(element.p)==0)
    $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + element.bp + ' Zbucks');
else
    $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + element.p + ' Zbucks');
```

You could also use `(element.bp || element.p)` as @Rayon mentioned in comment :

```
$('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + (element.bp || element.p) + ' Zbucks');
```

**NOTE :** This condition don't cover the case when the both are equals 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: May be `(element.bp || element.p)`. Note: OP is parsing all properties as `string` so `"0"` is will not be tested as true using `element.p==0`

Comment: Thanks @RayonDabre for your suggestion, updated my answer.

Comment: You missed the `if` condition mate..`(string)` will cast `0` as `"0"`